Computing the homology groups $H_0(S^7 \vee S^1)$ and $H_1(S^7 \vee S^1)$ of wedge sums
The question that I have to solve (or rather the computations I have to do) is the one in the title. The problem that I have with this is that we have never learned what wedge sums are, hence we don't have any results concerning them.
We have a hint which is the following:
You may use the weak Seifert-Van Kampen theorem in the following form:
Let $X$ be a topological space and $U, V \subseteq X$ open with $X= U \cup V$, let $z \in U \cap V$. If $U \cap V$ is path connected then $\pi_1(X,z)$ is generated by $i_{\#}(\pi_1(U,z))$ and $j_{\#} (\pi_1(V,z))$ where $i: U \to X$ and $j: V \to X$ are the inclusions. Note: $i_\#: \pi_1(U,x) \to \pi_1(X,x)$.
I have no idea how that hint could be related to the assignment since this is a result about fundamental groups and not homology groups. But since I'm relatively new to homology theory maybe there is something that I'm simply not considering. Help is appreciated.

The link to the fundamental group might be the result that $H_1(X)$ is the abelianisation of $\pi_1(X)$ (for $X$ path connected) --- see here.

The Hint is probably intended to give the result via the Hurewicz Theorem which identifies the first homology group as the abelianization of the fundamental group.
Hint: There is a cover by two open subsets $U$ and $V$ homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ and $S^7$ respectively such that $U \cap V$ is contractible.

That being said, this is more complicated than it needs to be in my humble opinion. A more reasonable approach is to use the most fundamental computational tool for homology which is known as excision. The hint above in my answer then directly answers your question for all homology groups in a very streamlined way.
In fact, this works for $X \vee Y$ for arbitrary $CW$-complexes or suitably nice spaces (namely that  $x$ has a contractible neighborhood in the wedge product where $X \vee Y := ((X,x) \coprod (Y,y))/\sim$ where $x \sim y$.)
